# Table Filed

Tags: vb.net, linq

My code that can get tablename in linq query is:

```
     Dim TY As Type = (From T In DB.Mapping.GetTables()
                       Where T.TableName = tableN
                       Select T.RowType.Type).SingleOrDefault
     Dim Table As ITable = DB.GetTable(TY)
     Dim mq = From t In Table Select t
```

tableN get from another form. I want  to access the fileld of Table and use in linq query .how?

for example:

```
Dim mq = From t In Table Select t.Code
```

please help me

Comment: 0  vote down
check
 

I don't know the the name and type of my selected table until query executed. how Can I use this Extension?

Answer (score 1):

Try using extension methods instead:

```
Dim mq = Table.Select( Function(t) t.Code );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your final select to look something like this:

```
Dim mq = From t In Table.OfType<XXX> Select t.Code
```

The only thing that you'll need to know now is what type is in that table.  Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something similar to this?

```
Dim p As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo = Table.GetType().GetProperty("Code")
Dim mq = From t in Table Select p.GetValue(t)
```